# Is a posibility to return custom complex objects JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, repository

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA. I'm using a custom JPQL query to group by some field and list of object.

My entity class:

```
public class Review {
    @ManyToOne
    private ApplicationUser applicationUser;
    private String month;
    private Integer monthNumber;
    private Integer year;
    private String rating;
}
```

My model class:

```
public class UserInformationExport {
    private String userGid;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private List<MonthlyReview> grades;
}
public class MonthlyReview {
    private String month;
    private Integer monthNumber;
    private String rating;
}
```

I try the following query, but didn't work. How can I build that list of objects ?

**UPDATE** solution without `GROUP BY`...

```
return entityManager.createQuery("select new path.UserInformationExport(app.gid, app.lastName, app.firstName," +
                        " (select new path.MonthlyReview(r.month, r.monthNumber, r.qualifier, r.rating) from Review r where r.year = :yr and r.applicationUser.id = app.id))" +
                        " from ApplicationUser app where app.id in (:ids)", UserInformationExport.class)
                .setParameter("yr", year)
                .setParameter("ids", ids)
                .getResultList();
```

but it throws the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getDataType() is not supported by ConstructorNode!
>
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.getDataType(ConstructorNode.java:129)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.QueryNode.getDataType(QueryNode.java:151)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructorArgumentTypes(ConstructorNode.java:158)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:133)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1260)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2395)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2261)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1523)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:602)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:825)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.createQuery(Unknown Source)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.createQuery(Unknown Source)

I would like to have something like this:

```
  [
    {
      "userGid" : "958",
      "lastName":"fad",
      "firstName":"fad",
      "grades" : [
        {
          "month": "Jan",
          "monthNumber":1,
          "qualifier":4,
          "rating":"wqfw"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```